# How to create responsive background img css for retina displays?

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design, background-image, retina-display

I have created a site with Twitter Bootstrap, however I cannot figure out why my background img in 2 divs are not being responsive when viewed on an iPhone 5 or iPhone 6 Plus. From my research, it appears to be a retina display issue, but I'm not finding a solution. The site is here: [caseyscuriouspath.com/expresscredentialing](http://caseyscuriouspath.com/expresscredentialing)

I have 2 different images, one on the section class="bg-1", and one on section class="bg-3". They respond find when I resize my browser, but when viewed on an iPhone they are pixelated blobs. I have tried jquery (backstretch - which worked, but does not give the parallax feel the clients really like), I have media queries for bg-1 that are not working, I have tried different background properties.